# sailsjs + passport authentication Same query running multiple times

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am using passportjs for authentication in sailsjs, everything is working fine, except when i ma starting node server with this command < LOG_QUERIES=true node app.js > it prints all the queries running on console. and it prints same queries multiple time at the time of login and auth check by id .